# Undefined symbol "locale_charset"

Tags: git

I'm trying to pull changes from repository.

```
[devserver ~/s3]$ git pull
/usr/local/bin/git: Undefined symbol "locale_charset"
```

Doing git pull as always. Getting these for the first time. Whats the problem?

Comment: Next time always provide versions of your OS, Git and the method you've installed it.  "Undefined symbol" in 99.9% cases means some (dynamic) linking error when starting up a process or loading a dynamically-linked library into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely a broken 1.9.0 build on FreeBSD http://www.opendevs.org/mqhsh/git-1-9-build-failes.html

People tell that the upgrading your git port [solves the issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.freebsd.ports-bugs/F2uihbqbtro).